# PostgreSQL returning first character of column name after join

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin

**I've 6 tables and I wanna join all the tables which have proper relations**

So there is a specific table which has only 5 columns, when I query it directly it returns all the data with the correct column name.

but when I join it with other tables it returns only the very first character of the column name.

[image]

**Update : Added Query**
[Link to the PSQL Query](https://gist.github.com/Akshay-N-Shaju/199c3713d36dcf3e767a7744f0fe3657)

**Update : Added PgAdmin screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Postgres would not do this.  There's either an issue with your query or the driver you are using.  Can you show us the query?

Comment: @Jeremy I've added the query gist to the question. Please check, Thank you :-)

Comment: `psql` does not return results in that format. I don't use pgAdmin but I am pretty sure it doesn't return results in that format either - both tools show a "tabular view" on the result. This looks like some other tool that converts the result into some kind of JSON.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's the same scenario in the pgadmin. I just extracted it so people can read it easily. Thanks for your response BTW

Comment: So how did you convert the result into a JSON value?

Comment: That query does not create JSON.  There must be something else converting the output of that query to JSON?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name FYI, I've added the PgAdmin screenshot to the question

Comment: @Jeremy  FYI, I've added the PgAdmin screenshot to the question

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense.  Postgres identifiers are limited to a max of 63 bytes, so you are bumping up against that limit.